# JSON Parse in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a JSON Object returned from server.

```
{
  "SOAP-ENV:Envelope": {
    "SOAP-ENV:Body": {
      "ADDWEBSOperationResponse": {
        "Num1": 10,
        "Result": 20,
        "Num2": 10,
        "xmlns": "http://www.**.**.Response.com"
      }
    },
    "xmlns:SOAP-ENV": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
    "xmlns:soapenv": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
    "xmlns:add": "http://www.**.**.Request.com"
  }
}
```

I wanted to print `Result` in my page. I was trying with `data.Result`but its not displaying the value.

Comment: data["SOAP-ENV:Envelope"]["SOAP-ENV:Body"]["ADDWEBSOperationResponse"].Result

Comment: And in case your data is formatted as string, do this first JSON.parse(data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it with

```
data['SOAP-ENV:Envelope']['SOAP-ENV:Body']['ADDWEBSOperationResponse'].Result
```

Comment: I am getting a JSON string from the server.. I didn't convert it to object. But still this worked for me.. But i wonder how can i convert it to JSON object. I tried `JSON.parse(data)`. But it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 4):

Use `bracket notation` as it is particularly useful for non-identifier-safe characters and also for accessing keys that you may not know ahead of time

```
data["SOAP-ENV:Envelope"]["SOAP-ENV:Body"]["ADDWEBSOperationResponse"]["Result"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I should be

```
data["SOAP-ENV:Envelope"]["SOAP-ENV:Body"]["ADDWEBSOperationResponse"].Result
```

You need to follow the hierarchy.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/39kp0fq4/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
data["SOAP-ENV:Envelope"]["SOAP-ENV:Body"]["ADDWEBSOperationResponse"].Result
```